# Finding the name of the blackberry in universal search Screen Name

Tags: java, blackberry

I want to develop an app which doesnot allow user to change the options which are preset. I used to check for the screen and pop it if the options screen occurs. But i found out that if i search for a specific option setting, It shows the setting which can be used.

Eg:

I cannot open options. But i can search for application management and open application settings.

How to get the name of the universal search screen when it is searching for a specific option?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. My phone is my phone, not yours.  RIM has better solutions for corporate IT restrictions.

Comment: Fortunately, users afflicted by your app should be able to uninstall it via javaloader or BBSAK.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue then can you enlighten me on which solutions exist for IT restrictions. Ps: The phones being referred to are all my phones which are meant to be used for a specific purpose only.